# Read data from HID keyboard device in java

Tags: java, hid

how to read data from a single HID USB keyboard among multiple without using a global windows hook in java.

I had tried global windows hook using jnativehook lib but in that, it is not possible to identify the device from which input came.

i had also tried to use usb4java lib but failed due to:

[image]

please suggest any way to getting out of this issue.

Comment: I've made a thing like this on windows using JNA and listening to windows events. It's very platform specific.

Comment: Which kind of windows event @Tokazio and can you share code snippet or reference?

Comment: it's called WindowsHook, with jna you can 'install' a hook and listen to system events. Seach for SetWinEventHook and JNA (User32Ext).

Comment: Is it possible to identify from which device key is pressed among multiple keyboards because I had already tried global hook using jnativehook lib in java

Comment: Can't tell you more on that... See details about this hook https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)

Comment: And i think this one is interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256539/when-hooking-windows-message-loop-whats-kbdllhookstructs-dwextrainfo-for